# Bootstrap: CSS - height of list-group-item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please Consider follow JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7W2r4/12/

As you might notice: the `list-group-item` is fully collapsed. And i can't seem to make it autoadjust. (e.g. `height:auto;`)

yet when i supply the css rule:`height:20px;`, then the row size is adjusted.
How can i make the height of an list-group-item to adjust to size of the content?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add `overflow:hidden` or other "clear-fix" code to the list-group-item if you need to retain the floats within the items.  Floats always cause problems with the height of the floated items.  Clearing them or setting overflow will force the height to be calculated properly. See [CSS: Floating divs have 0 height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024494/css-floating-divs-have-0-height) for more info on this.

```
.list-group-item
{
  overflow:hidden;  
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Since you are using Bootstrap you could add the `class="clearfix"` to HTML for the `list-group-items`

Comment: Oh i wasn't aware that the influences of floats were that big. And i never knew they had any impact on the height! Thank you for you explination.

Comment: I've added a link to another question that helps explain this effect.  There are a lot of ways to make this less of a problem.  there are various approaches to clear floats.  The oldest is to add a `<br style="clear:both"/>` after the container holding the floats.  It is now frowned upon as it is not semantic.  Most CSS frameworks contain a `.clearfix` or similarly named rule that fixes this.

Comment: for me to scale crucial was ` overflow:hidden;  `

Answer (score 5):

Removing the `float: left;` from `.itemDescription` will fix your issue [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Last1Here/7W2r4/15/), so the complete style for `.itemDescription` will be:

```
.itemDescription
{
    width: 30%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    line-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Your Right! But why does a  {float: left} have influence on a the height?

Comment: @svranken: maybe reading through that article might help: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing

Comment: Floating element heights are not used in the calculation of its parents height by design, the reasoning for this I am not to clear on, i believe its because they are ' taken out of the flow of the document'. You can make the parent take the floating item into consideration by [clearing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#Clearing_floats) the float or remove the unneeded float in your case.

Comment: Yes! The section about "Containing floats" was very helpfull!