# Bootstrap 3: Reduce height of list-group-item in list-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, height, size

I want to reduce height of list-group-item.

```
    <ul class="list-group" style="max-height: 200px;overflow: auto;">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="i in filters">
            {{i}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

How can I do? Should I add custom css class?
[image]

Answer (score 61):

If you are using bootstrap 4 then solution is easy, no need to write any new class.

We can use py-0/py-1/py-2/py-3/py-4 class according to your need with LI element:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item py-2" ng-repeat="i in filters">
        {{i}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where property is one of:

- m - margin
- p - padding

Where sides is one of:

- t - top
- b - bottom
- l - left
- r - right
- x - left & right
- y - top & bottom

Where Number is one of:

- 1: .25rem = 4px
- 2: .50rem = 8px
- 3: .75rem = 12px
- 4: 1rem = 16px

Answer (score 11):

Just override bootstrap's CSS-style in your styles file. Please keep in mind, that you should insert your file after bootstrap's CSS-file.

```
/* Overrides list-group-item from Bootstrap */ 
.list-group-item {
    padding: 3px 10px
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is to update bootstrap.css as seen in Peter Wooster's answer here: [Bootstrap: CSS - height of list-group-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285260/bootstrap-css-height-of-list-group-item).  To change the height of a list-group-item, update the "height" property.  If you set the height to a non-default value, you probably also want to change vertical "padding" offset.

The alternative to updating the CSS is to include a style attribute in every <li> or <a> tag that contains a list-group-item.  Here are the default values:

```
<li class="list-group-item" style="height: 40px; padding: 10px 15px;">
```

If you want to make the boxes smaller, try:

```
<li class="list-group-item" style="height: 30px; padding: 5px 15px;">
```

Be aware that word wrap <strike>misbehaves</strike> behaves differently when the list-group-item's height is fixed.