# How to put footer block at the same y-line as image?

Tags: html, css

I make list of news with custom css(I do not use any bootstrap or similar library)
and with image at left side and content at right side. Also I need to put div with footer-block class
below the content at the same y-line as image.
But result is different a bit : https://prnt.sc/KRY1kmwoUNHP

I expected that setting in   .footer-block properties

```
height: 24px;
position:relative;
bottom:-24px;
```

will make it, but it does not.

How to fix it with cross platform decision?

```css
.news-block-wrapper {
  news-block-wrapper
}

.news-title {
  width: 1094px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 440px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #D4D4E1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*border: 2px dotted yellow;*/
}

.news-content-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  width: 1332px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 54px;
  left: 440px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B0B0BD;
}

.img-left-float {
  float: left !important;
}

.news-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  border: 2px dotted yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-block {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -24px;
}

.news-content {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-align: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-block-wrapper">
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/860/640" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        16=&gt;Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Non qui vel quia excepturi. Dolorum ut voluptatem neque accusamus voluptatum. 
      </p>
      <div class="footer-block">
        16=&gt;Links
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        2=&gt;Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo
        est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium. Repellat vero qui dolorem error
        perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem
        qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore.
        Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium
        adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit
        voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores.
        Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas
        et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum
        eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci
        velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis
        unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa
        quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.
      </p>
      <div class="footer-block">
        2=&gt;Links
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just clear the float (of the image) in `.footer-block`?

Comment: Sorry, did not catch. How that could salve my problem ?

Comment: From what I can make out from the question, you want `.footer-block` to be displayed below the image? Check out the suggested question below for further details on floating elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Floating divs have 0 height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024494/css-floating-divs-have-0-height)

Comment: Not below the image, at the same line as bottom of the image. I show it in printscreen. I did not find decision in your link.

Comment: So what about the 2nd paragraph with more content? How do you want to proceed there then? Keep in mind that floating elements don't take up "height" in the DOM

Comment: Any news has 4 blocks : image at left, content at right.  content has 3 blocks : title, text(cane be very long) at footer(class footer-block). I just try to put footer-block at bottom of the content block. There is list of news

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

I applied `position: sticky` and `top: 100%` on `.footer-block`, so it's pushed all the way down to the bottom of the container.

```css
.news-title {
  width: 1094px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 440px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #D4D4E1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*border: 2px dotted yellow;*/
}

.news-content-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  width: 1332px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 54px;
  left: 440px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B0B0BD;
}

.img-left-float {
  float: left !important;
}

.news-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  border: 2px dotted yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-block {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 24px;
  /*position: relative;
  bottom: -24px; */
  position: sticky;
  top: 100%;
}

.news-content {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-align: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-block-wrapper">
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/860/640" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        16=&gt;Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Non qui vel quia excepturi. Dolorum ut voluptatem neque accusamus voluptatum.
      </p>
      <div class="footer-block">
        16=&gt;Links
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        2=&gt;Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo
        est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium. Repellat vero qui dolorem error
        perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem
        qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore.
        Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium
        adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit
        voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores.
        Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas
        et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum
        eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci
        velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis
        unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa
        quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.
      </p>
      <div class="footer-block">
        2=&gt;Links
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure whether or not you need the `.footer-block`-element to align with `.news-content.` If so, you can apply this:

```css
.footer-block {
   width: calc(100% - 404px); /* 100% of container - (img width (400px) + border of .footer-block (2px) */
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

This would only work for the layout where the links must be on the same level as the image though.

```css
.news-title {
  width: 1094px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 440px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #D4D4E1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*border: 2px dotted yellow;*/
}

.news-content-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  width: 1332px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 54px;
  left: 440px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B0B0BD;
}

.img-left-float {
  float: left !important;
}

.news-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  border: 2px dotted yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-block {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 24px;
  /*position: relative;
  bottom: -24px; */
  position: sticky;
  top: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 404px);
  margin-left: auto;
}

.news-content {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-align: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-block-wrapper">
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/860/640" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        16=&gt;Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Non qui vel quia excepturi. Dolorum ut voluptatem neque accusamus voluptatum.
      </p>
      <div class="footer-block">
        16=&gt;Links
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        2=&gt;Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo
        est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium. Repellat vero qui dolorem error
        perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem
        qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore.
        Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium
        adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit
        voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores.
        Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas
        et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum
        eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci
        velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis
        unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa
        quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.
      </p>
      <div class="footer-block">
        2=&gt;Links
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  
}
.image img{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
  .news-title {
        width: 1094px;
        height: 24px;
        top: 20px;
        left: 440px;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 24px;
        color: #D4D4E1;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
       .news-content-wrapper {
        display: inline;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left:10px;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 24px;
        color: #B0B0BD;
    }
    .news{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      justify-content:space-between;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="image">
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/860/640" alt="Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.">
</div>
<div class="news-content-wrapper news">
<div >
            <h5 class="news-title">
                <a href="">
                    16=&gt;Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.
                </a>
            </h5>
            
            <p class="news-content">Non qui vel quia excepturi. Dolorum ut voluptatem neque accusamus voluptatum. Libero sit quae fugit sequi. Eum consequuntur delectus magni fugit adipisci. Consequatur velit consectetur omnis inventore tenetur. Voluptas nesciunt voluptatem perferendis consequatur fugit id sit magni. Cupiditate dolor modi ipsum eum similique. Neque vitae minus vel velit dolores blanditiis porro. Occaecati odit sequi et ut dolore autem.
            </p>
            
</div>

            <div class="footer-block">
                16=&gt;Links
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves OP's problem. Code-only answers are not good answers.

Comment: Yes, please explain at the salvation point

Comment: I tried to remade by code by your exam[le by your code and failed. It losts working with long text and left float. Could you please to remade your example according to your code ?

Comment: After some additive tests I see that property
display: inline of class .news-content-wrapper conflicts with property
display:flex; of .news. So I lose floating left or "links" at the same level with image.
How can I combine both these properties?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the footer block after the clear div and removed the `bottom` property. It looks good now.

```css
.news-block-wrapper {
  news-block-wrapper
}

.news-title {
  width: 1094px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 440px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #D4D4E1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*border: 2px dotted yellow;*/
}

.news-content-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  width: 1332px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 54px;
  left: 440px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B0B0BD;
}

.img-left-float {
  float: left !important;
}

.news-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  border: 2px dotted yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-block {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.news-content {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-align: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-block-wrapper">
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/860/640" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        16=&gt;Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Non qui vel quia excepturi. Dolorum ut voluptatem neque accusamus voluptatum. 
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="footer-block">
        16=&gt;Links
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        2=&gt;Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo
        est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium. Repellat vero qui dolorem error
        perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem
        qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore.
        Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium
        adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit
        voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores.
        Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas
        et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum
        eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci
        velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis
        unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa
        quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="footer-block">
        2=&gt;Links
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to study and use `display: grid;` and `display: flex` to mount your next webpages to be more responsive.

But here is an easy solution to your problem without need to change your HTML, you only need to change your CSS.

The points i've changed were:

```
.news-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  border: 2px dotted yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-block {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -24px;
}
```

to:

```
.news-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  border: 2px dotted yellow;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}

.footer-block {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is the code running:

```css
.news-block-wrapper {
  news-block-wrapper
}

.news-title {
  width: 1094px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 440px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #D4D4E1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*border: 2px dotted yellow;*/
}

.news-content-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  width: 1332px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 54px;
  left: 440px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #B0B0BD;
}

.img-left-float {
  float: left !important;
}

.news-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  border: 2px dotted yellow;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}

.footer-block {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.news-content {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-align: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-block-wrapper">
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/860/640" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        16=&gt;Test news Maxime assumenda natus neque.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Non qui vel quia excepturi. Dolorum ut voluptatem neque accusamus voluptatum. 
      </p>
      <div class="footer-block">
        16=&gt;Links
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="news-row">

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" class="img-left-float news-img" alt="Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.">

    <div class="news-content-wrapper">
      <h5 class="news-title">
        <a href="">
                        2=&gt;Test news Magni vel et impedit hic.
                    </a>
      </h5>

      <p class="news-content">Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo
        est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium. Repellat vero qui dolorem error
        perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem
        qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore.
        Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium
        adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit
        voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores.
        Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas
        et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum
        eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci
        velit eveniet consequatur at culpa quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis
        unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.Repellat vero qui dolorem error perspiciatis itaque magni labore. Veniam fuga saepe velit suscipit voluptatem. Corrupti omnis eum quas et nostrum labore. Doloribus adipisci velit eveniet consequatur at culpa
        quo. Delectus consequuntur commodi quo est delectus sed voluptatem qui. Incidunt voluptas sit laudantium adipisci officiis incidunt dolores. Tempore cupiditate est ab cum eos sapiente. Architecto eius debitis unde asperiores omnis veniam laudantium.
      </p>
      <div class="footer-block">
        2=&gt;Links
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No I expec a bit different for block with small text https://prnt.sc/ktVIaSA6mUly